# kivy Can't scroll using scrollview even after setting height: minimum_height

Tags: python, kivy

Almost all of the similar problems I've read had the same solution, which I've already done from the start. So I don't know the problem I am encountering, but it may be from the stack layouts I have used.

Python File

```
class Task_List(BoxLayout):
pass


class CheckBox_Area(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "lr-tb"
        self.padding = (dp(20), dp(10), dp(20), dp(0))
        for i in range(0, 20):
            size = dp(40)
            b = CheckBox(size_hint=(None, None), size=(size, size))
            self.add_widget(b)

class List_Area(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "lr-tb"
        self.padding = (dp(10), dp(10), dp(20), dp(20))
        for i in range(0, 20):
            b = TextInput(text=str(f"Task {i}"), size_hint=(1, None), size=(0, dp(40)))
            self.add_widget(b)
```

kv file

```
Scroll:

<Task_List>:
    max: False
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Tasks for Today"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
    Label:
        text: "Area for Quotes"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        CheckBox_Area:

        List_Area:
            size_hint: 5, 1


<CheckBox_Area>:

<List_Area>:


<Scroll@ScrollView>:
    Task_List:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

Answer (score 0):

Every children of `ScrollView` should have at least one explicit size value(s) (depending on the scrolling direction).

Thus the changes you need,

```py
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        CheckBox_Area:

        List_Area:
            size_hint: 5, None # Note that `size_hint_x` value should be between 0 and 1 otherwise you may get unexpected result.
            height: self.minimum_height
```

### Edit:

Since `ScrollView` accepts a single `widget`, the statement *'Every children of ScrollView should have at least one explicit...'* is invalid. What I wanted to mean is that this is applicable to the widget's (that single `widget`) children so that that `widget`'s at least one size value becomes explicit.